# How to save and load HTML file using Python or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I am creating a web application that uses HTML, Javascript, jQuery and Python. I have a few sections that allow user 1 to log in and set some items on the webpage and after user 1 logs out, user 2 can log in and he can see those items.
However, the current situation is that if user 2 refreshes the page, everything will be gone.

FYI, I'm using CherryPy as my localhost web server. I need some explanation on how this can be done and maybe some simple solution. I can provide more information if needed. Thank you.

I've just found something called [TiddlyWiki](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html#TiddlySaver). I'm not sure if it suits the purpose.

Comment: Aren't you using a database?

Comment: @bfavaretto umm i don't think so. i'm a total beginner to this :/

Comment: You should be then. How are you handling logins without a database? And where are you persisting the data between the two user sessions you mentioned?

Comment: oh by "login" it means log into a device, all the authentication is done in the device. sorry for forgetting to clarify that. And i just pass the data around in a single page using jQuery. Then i hide and show different things for the 2 users.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is still unclear. What kind of device are you talking about?

Comment: it is like a home automation system. i would like to find out if it is possible to save the localhost webpage generate by the python file into a html, then when user 2 is detected as "login", that html page will be loaded or something